# Remove leading zeros pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I want to remove leading zeros of one column in pyspark?

[image]

Comment: check: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#ltrim. `ltrim(trimStr, str)` - Removes the leading string contains the characters from the trim string

Answer (score 14):

Another way is to use `regexp-replace` here:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.show()
df = df.withColumn('subcategory', F.regexp_replace('subcategory', r'0', ''))
df = df.withColumn('subcategory_label', F.regexp_replace('subcategory_label', r'0', ''))
df.show()
```

The input DataFrame:

```
+-----------+-----------------+--------+
|subcategory|subcategory_label|category|
+-----------+-----------------+--------+
|      00EEE|        00EEE FFF|   Drink|
|    0000EEE|        00EEE FFF|   Fruit|
|       0EEE|       000EEE FFF|    Meat|
+-----------+-----------------+--------+
```

The output DataFrame:

```
+-----------+-----------------+--------+
|subcategory|subcategory_label|category|
+-----------+-----------------+--------+
|        EEE|          EEE FFF|   Drink|
|        EEE|          EEE FFF|   Fruit|
|        EEE|          EEE FFF|    Meat|
+-----------+-----------------+--------+
```

If it needs the `0`s to be at the beginning of the strings, you can use these to make sure no middle `0` get removed.:

```
df = df.withColumn('subcategory', F.regexp_replace('subcategory', r'^[0]*', ''))
df = df.withColumn('subcategory_label', F.regexp_replace('subcategory_label', r'^[0]*', ''))
```

Comment: F.regexp_replace('subcategory', r'^[0]*', '') - this one is very useful. Thanks @niuer

Answer (score -1):

You can use `lstrip('0')` to get rid of leading 0's in a string.
To do this via pyspark, make a UDF for the same

```
import pyspark.functions as F
udf = F.UserDefinedFunctions(lambda x: x.lstrip('0'), spark_types.StringType())
```

Comment: I guess the downvote is due to performance concerns.